# How to correct use of List<List<String>>

Tags: java, collections

I have `List<List<String>>`

```
    PcpCharacteristic pcpCharacteristic = new PcpCharacteristic();

    PcpCharacteristicValue pcpCharacteristicValue = new PcpCharacteristicValue();

    //  if (allCharacteristics.get(i) != null) {

    for (List<String> list : allCharacteristics) {

      // name of lists Characteristics
      pcpCharacteristic.setCharacteristic(list.get(0));

      for (int j = 1; j < list.size(); j++) {

        // value from lists of Characteristics
        pcpCharacteristicValue.setValue(String.valueOf(j));
      }
    }
```

I need to take get (0) from each sublist and put it in one table (This is the name of the sheets). And put the rest of the elements in each subsheet, except for get(0), into the field of another table.
Сan you please tell me how to pass in one cycle for each sublist

Comment: You might want to read [ask] and elaborate. What exactly is the question? What are you struggling with? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Thomas I add more information

Comment: Weaving the title into the question, clearly, the sig of `PcpCharacteristicValue::setValue` is `List<List<?>>` (see title), and that makes this code not compile for known confusing reasons. I admit, this required some 'newbie archeology' skills.

Comment: @aleksandr1994 your additions did nothing whatsoever to clarify the problem. For future reference, include a self-contained example. In this case, PcpCharacteristicValue's source, or at least the relevant part of it. You kinda half knew it was relevant (given that you named `List<List<?>>` in your question title).

Comment: From what I can tell, the code should work just fine except that for the `for` loop, you would need to use `List<?> list` to work with `List<List<?>>`. As it stands, there is no question

Comment: Let me try to _guess_: is `pcpCharacteristicValue.setValue(String.valueOf(j));` not working correctly and hence you are asking? Does it fail to compile or are the values overwritten? And where is the `List<List<?>>` being used or where do you think it should be used?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer we don't know the type of `allCharacteristics` but given that "I have `List<List<String>>`" that might be its type. In that case the for loop should just be fine.

Comment: @Thomas I have List<List<String>> allCharacteristics . And I need to take only the first element in each sublist and put these first elements in one table in the database. And put all other values ​​in these sublists into a field in another table. For some reason, in the code, I only go through the first sublist. Type of values - String

Comment: "For some reason, in the code, I only go through the first sublist." - I don't see any reason for this in the code you've posted. `for (List<String> list : allCharacteristics)` would loop over _all_ lists unless you end the list early which I don't see you doing (there might be an exception that we don't know about though). "Type of values - String" - So I _assume_ instead of `setValue(String.valueOf(j))` you want `setValue(list.get(j))`. However, the name `setValue(...)` might hint at a problem with values being overwritten - again just a guess because we lack the details.

Comment: @user16320675 
what is so hard to understand about this code? for (List<String> list : allCharacteristics) - loop through a sheet that has subsheets. pcpCharacteristic.setCharacteristic(list.get(0)) - write only the first elements from each sublist. for (int j = 1; j < list.size(); j++) - we take and write in the field of another table from each sheet all the elements except index 0. it's just that I don't go through all the sublists using this code, only for some reason on the third one .. Tell me, is it clear now ??

Comment: @user16320675 yes, I'm asking the wrong question, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need something similar to:

```
List<List<String> allCharacteristics = ...  // or method parameter
Table table = ...                           // or method parameter

for (List<String> list : allCharacteristics) {
    var iter = list.iterator();
    var sheet = new Sheet(iter.next());
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        var subsheet = new SubSheet(iter.next();
        sheet.addSubsheet(subsheet);
    }
}
```

Please consider this being just some pseudo-code - missing some checks and details - also no idea what the `PcpCharacteristic` and `PcpCharacteristicValue` roles are (which is the table, which a sheet or subsheet, what data they store, which methods they offer, ...)

Answer (score 0):

The signature has to be `List<? extends List<?>>`:

```
class Test {
  void a(List<List<?>> list) {}
  void b(List<? extends List<?>> list) {}
  void test() {
    List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    b(list); // fine
    a(list); // error
  }
}
```